# Path variables in Apache Camel rest route

Tags: rest, web-services, apache-camel

I would like to use path variables in my REST route URL in the following way:

```
rest().post("/companies/{companyId}/branches/branchId={branchId}");
```

The companyId can be properly retrieved as header, however, "branchId={branchId}" is treated as literal string. Therefore request to:
`/companies/100/branches/branchId=200` - will return 404 not found.
but
`/companies/100/branches/branchId={branchId}` - will enter the route.

I would like to use **branchId** as header, in the same way as **companyId**, without having to change the structure of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Every path or query parameter can be received through the headers in Apache Camel. You can retrieve the headers with using the simple expression;

`${header.your-header}`

So you can retrieve the parameters as below;

| parameter | simple expression |
| --- | --- |
| companyId | ${header.companyId} |
| branchId | ${header.branchId} |

Here is a working Route example that I've made for you;

```java
package com.bzdgn.camelso.route;

import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.model.rest.RestBindingMode;

public class RestEndpointRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        rest()
            .post("/companies/{companyId}/branches/{branchId}")
            .consumes("text/plain")
            .produces("text/plain")
            .to("direct:handle-post");
        
        from("direct:handle-post")
            .id("post-route")
            .log("Received Body: ${body}")
            .log("Company Id: ${header.companyId}")
            .log("Branch  Id: ${header.branchId}")
            .setBody(simple("CompanyId = ${header.companyId} \nBranchId  = ${header.branchId}"))
            .convertBodyTo(String.class);
        
        restConfiguration()
            .component("netty-http")
            .host("localhost")
            .port("8080")
            .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.auto);
    }

}
```

The logs will be as below if you send a HTTP Post Request to the designated URL;

```
2021-05-28 21:13:30 INFO  HttpServerBootstrapFactory:53 - BootstrapFactory on port 8080 is using bootstrap configuration: [NettyServerBootstrapConfiguration{protocol='http', host='localhost', port=8080, broadcast=false, sendBufferSize=65536, receiveBufferSize=65536, receiveBufferSizePredictor=0, workerCount=0, bossCount=1, keepAlive=true, tcpNoDelay=true, reuseAddress=true, connectTimeout=10000, backlog=0, serverInitializerFactory=org.apache.camel.component.netty.http.HttpServerInitializerFactory@ae3540e, nettyServerBootstrapFactory=null, options=null, ssl=false, sslHandler=null, sslContextParameters='null', needClientAuth=false, enabledProtocols='TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2, keyStoreFile=null, trustStoreFile=null, keyStoreResource='null', trustStoreResource='null', keyStoreFormat='JKS', securityProvider='SunX509', passphrase='null', bossGroup=null, workerGroup=null, networkInterface='null', reconnect='true', reconnectInterval='10000'}]
2021-05-28 21:13:30 INFO  NettyComponent:164 - Creating shared NettyConsumerExecutorGroup with 17 threads
2021-05-28 21:13:31 INFO  SingleTCPNettyServerBootstrapFactory:182 - ServerBootstrap binding to localhost:8080
2021-05-28 21:13:33 INFO  NettyConsumer:77 - Netty consumer bound to: localhost:8080
2021-05-28 21:13:33 INFO  AbstractCamelContext:2983 - Routes startup summary (total:2 started:2)
2021-05-28 21:13:33 INFO  AbstractCamelContext:2988 -     Started post-route (direct://handle-post)
2021-05-28 21:13:33 INFO  AbstractCamelContext:2988 -     Started route1 (rest://post:/companies/%7BcompanyId%7D/branches/%7BbranchId%7D)
2021-05-28 21:13:33 INFO  AbstractCamelContext:3000 - Apache Camel 3.10.0 (camel-1) started in 3s337ms (build:93ms init:274ms start:2s970ms)
2021-05-28 21:13:35 INFO  post-route:166 - Received Body: Example text body here
2021-05-28 21:13:35 INFO  post-route:166 - Company Id: my-custom-company
2021-05-28 21:13:35 INFO  post-route:166 - Branch  Id: my-custom-branch-id
```

And you can test it via postman like this. The request, and the headers listed in the below images, and do not forget to add **"Content Type: text/plain"**, because that's defined in the route that it will consume and produce "text/plain".

[image: Postman Request]
[image: Postman Headers]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, it misses the main purpose of this question, which is: how to keep the given structure, especially the part /branchId={branchId}. In your answer, you omit the "branchId=" part.

Comment: @mar3g You are right, but this is about using special characters in URI. I've tried using %3D instead of an equal sign but still, it returns 404. I'll get back working on this after my shift is finished ;)